# An infinite set of non-intersecting discs must be countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Prove that any set of non-intersecting discs on the plane is countable. I literally have no idea on how to tackle this question.

Answer (score 8):

Since every disk contains a rational point there is an injective function from the set of disks to the set of points with rational coordinates. Just send each disk to one of its points wih rational coordinates. Since the disks are non-intersecting this function is injective. Therefore the set of disks has the same cardinality as a subset of $\mathbb Q^2$

Comment: Lovely and simple

Comment: That's a great answer, but how do you know that every disk contains a rational point?

Comment: Do you know how to prove there is a rational number between any two different numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Every disk contains a rational point. The reason for this is because Q is dense in R. That means any interval (a,b) that is a subset of R has infinitely many rational numbers. What I don't get is how you would show that one of its point with rational coordinates. This isn't a answer. I just don't have enough reputation to comment haha

Comment: ok, suppose the disk has center $(h,k)$ and radius $r$. By what you just said there exists a rational $x$ in the iterval $(h-r,h+r)$. select that $x$. By what you just said there is a rational $y$ in the interval $(k-\sqrt{r^2-(h-x)^2},k+\sqrt{r^2-(h-x)^2})$. the point $(x,y)$ is rational and is inside the disk.